# What could be the reason my network is unstable until I switch to a new MAC adress

Tags: networking, connection

I receive internet through Wireless WAN antenna and my main device ( router) is served with a NATed IP. Network connection is erratic most of time until router gets a new MAC address ( manually added ). That is what I've found after a lot of experimentation. ISP claims everything working. Other than switching ISP, looking for any recommendation

Comment: Are you changing the MAC address of the 'WAN' interface or the 'LAN' interface? Does this occur only with the _original_ MAC of the router, or does it repeat with _every_ new MAC address?

Comment: ISP>Antenna > Router ( here) > My network.
It  happens with every one of them, including the original. If I'm having network issues, changing the MAC intermediately resolves them but after a time ( could be minutes, hours or a couple of days ) it starts malfunctioning again